# Mysql Error After Adding Many Datas

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi

I was adding records to my mysql server and something happened. I rebooted my raspberry pi and realized that i can't start mysql.

Error when i use phpmyadmin:

```
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

Status mysql service:

```
    ● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-01-11 00:27:52 MSK; 45s ago
  Process: 2186 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 11 00:37:38 svs /etc/init.d/mysql[6188]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian...ted in
Jan 11 00:37:38 svs /etc/init.d/mysql[6188]: [61B blob data]
Jan 11 00:37:38 svs /etc/init.d/mysql[6188]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/...' (2)'
Jan 11 00:37:38 svs /etc/init.d/mysql[6188]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.so...xists!
Jan 11 00:37:38 svs /etc/init.d/mysql[6188]:
Jan 11 00:37:38 svs mysql[5450]: Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ...failed!
Jan 11 00:37:38 svs systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 11 00:37:38 svs systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Jan 11 00:37:38 svs systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
```

Mysql -u -p returns

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

Thanks for any help :))

Edit:
Solved the problem with reinstalling mysql.

Comment: is your mysql service running?

Comment: No, I can't start it

Comment: You probably find the reason mysql crashed in mysql's own error log. The log in your question is useless for determining what has gone wrong.